# How to implement `Futures::poll` over internal `async fn func(mut self)` method that takes full ownership?

Tags: rust, async-await

How to implement `Futures::poll` the the following code that will call `async` method with full ownership to the `self`?

```
use anyhow::Error;
use futures::Future;
use futures::channel::oneshot;
use futures::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;

struct MyLongTask {
    rx: oneshot::Receiver<()>,
}

impl MyLongTask {
    // The method and full ownership to `self` is important to keep!
    async fn recv(mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {
        self.rx.await.map_err(|_| Error::msg("can't recv"))
    }
}

// TryFuture not necessary here
impl Future for MyLongTask {
    type Output = Result<(), Error>;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        todo!("how to `self.recv().await` here?")
    }
}

fn main() { }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f076051e8a3b42d7811ae6128c3601a7) if needed.

Comment: What's the benefit of making a `MyLongTask` future over just calling `rx.await.map_err(...)` directly? What's the goal?

Comment: That's the simplified example of the struct with many many fields that have to be consumed.

Comment: If `MyLongTask` has many fields and needs to be consumed and processed by `recv`, why make `MyLongTask` itself a future? `my_long_task.recv()` already returns a future that does what you want, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `self.recv()` inside `poll` firstly because it does not own `self`, and secondly because it is *not* `async`.
[`Future::poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#the-poll-method) is synchronous but must return quickly regardless of whether a return value is ready (that's the whole idea of `Poll::Pending`).
In your case you should simply delegate the `poll` to `self.rx`: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8ed375a7116c49301acfbe962acf39e))

```
impl Future for MyLongTask {
    type Output = Result<(), Error>;
    
    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match Pin::new(&mut self.rx).poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(x) => Poll::Ready(x.map_err(|_| Error::msg("can't recv"))),
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead of using `task.recv().await`, you can just do `task.await`.
I'd also suggest you **either** implement `Future` **or** provide the `recv` method.
Otherwise you could run into trouble later when you change one implementation and forget to change the other.

Comment: *"and secondly because it is not `async`"* - to be pedantic you can *call* an `async` function from a non-`async` one, you just can't *`.await`* it. The returned future just won't do anything without something driving it forward.

Comment: It's not exactly what I needed, but also helpful.